# Multicolumn paper-and-pencil form with indentation issue

Tags: indentation, forms, questionnaire

Hi All and Happy New Year!

I am trying to create a paper-and-pencil form which should look like as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[landscape,left=2cm,right=0.5cm,top=1.5cm,  bottom=1.5cm,headsep=1cm,headheight=1.0cm,]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx, ragged2e} 
\usepackage{wasysym} % \Square

\begin{document}
\LARGE \textbf{My Long Informative Title}  \par
\vspace{1em}
\normalsize 

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{p{3.3cm}   X@{\hskip 3mm}  X@{\hskip 3mm}    X@{\hskip 3mm}}
\hline
\textbf{Items} & \textbf{Constellation 1} & \textbf{Constellation 2} & \textbf{Constellation 3} \\ \hline
The First Issue & \Square \, Lorem ipsum dolor. & \Square \, At vero eos et accusam. & \Square \, Duis autem vel eum iriure. \\ \hline
The Second and also the Third Issue & \Square \, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr. \par \Square \, At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. \par \Square \,Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. & \Square \, Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit.   \par \Square \, Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci & \Square \, Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option. \\ 
\hline

\end{tabularx}\par

\end{document}
```

That means, it has four columns, thereof three have the descriptions of selectable options. I did not find a suitable package for the task and merely draw this form manually.

This works in general, however the layout looks ugly if the description of an option takes more than one line. The text on the subsequent lines should indent and not start under the checkbox as it does now.

So my questions are whether this is achieveble without a special package or probably besser whether there is a package that can provide the layout I need.

Many thanks!

Comment: Will the table fit into the page or will you need page breaks?

Comment: Hi, and thank you! The real table is long so I will indeed need page breaks.

Comment: In that case, replace `tabularx` with `xltabular`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the following suits your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[landscape,left=2cm,right=0.5cm,top=1.5cm,  bottom=1.5cm,headsep=1cm,headheight=1.0cm,]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx, ragged2e} 
\usepackage{wasysym} % \Square

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\LARGE \textbf{My Long Informative Title}  \par
\vspace{1em}
\normalsize 

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3.3cm}*{3}{>{\Square}l@{~}X}}
\toprule
\textbf{Items} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Constellation 1}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Constellation 2}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Constellation 3}} \\ 
\midrule
The First Issue 
    && Lorem ipsum dolor. 
        && At vero eos et accusam. 
            && Duis autem vel eum iriure.  
    \\ 
\midrule
The Second and also the Third Issue 
    &&  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci
        && Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit. 
        && Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option. \\
    &&  At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. \\
    &&  Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   \\ 
\bottomrule

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it looks great! As for page breaks I thought of making a tabularx environment for each page. Is there a better way with my layout? Thanks again!

Comment: Just read about xltabular in your comment above. Thank you! I will try it.

Comment: Hi, on a second look there is a issue if there are more options to the right as to the left:
<code>The Second and also the Third Issue 
    &&  One.
         &&Two.
          && Three. \\
    && 
      && Extra. \\ </code>
Here, there is an unnecessary checkbox in the column "Constellation 1" left to "Extra".
Is there a way to conditionally switch on/off the checkbox?

Comment: @v_e: You can add `\newcommand{\nobox}{\multicolumn{1}{l}{}}` to your preamble and use it as follows:  `The Second and also the Third Issue && One. &&Two. && Three. \\ &\nobox& && Extra. \\ `

Comment: Works like a charm! Many thanks!